# What are those Javascript functions parameters and how does it work ? (native parameters)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this tiny bit of (pure) js code, for example :

```
document.getElementById("example").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

What exactly is this "event" parameter ? I could also call it "myGoat", right ? Where/when is it defined that this parameter refers to the actual event ?

Another jQuery example :

```
request = $.ajax({
        url: "cre_devis.php",
        type: "post",
        data: someData
});
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jQueryXMLHttpRequest){
    document.getElementById("serverAnswer").innerHTML = response;
});
```

How are `response`, `textStatus` and `jQueryXMLHttpRequest` defined ? I suppose it is related to the `.done` method ?

Comment: 1st example: you can call the parameter whatever you want (event, evt, e), it will always be the `event` object, because it is defined as such in ecmascript.
2nd example: same thing, three parameters are passed to the `done` callback function (defined in the jQuery library).

Comment: Callbacks & Callback parameters :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are callback functions and they receive the parameter from the code which is calling it which in this case happens on some event such as an event.

Every function in JavaScript is a Function object. You can pass it as a parameter to some other function like any other object. Example:

```
function bar(value, callback) {
  callback(value);
}

bar('actual value', function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

You can read about callback functions at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function